# Upload photo from gallery not work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

Hi all when i try to select an image profile if i try to upload a photo from camera all works good, but if i upload a photo from gallery i not show anything. The function for opening the gallery and select the photo works but after selected the photo she should appear but not appear anything. 
Hope you help me. Thank you. 
Here is the code :

```
public class UpdateProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
ImageView imgProfile;
Button btnSaveProfile,btnMyadd;
EditText edtName,edtEmail,edtNumber,edtWebsite;
TextView txtname,txtEmail,txtNumber,txtWebsite;
ProgressDialog progressBar;
String name,email,number,website;
private String selectedImagePath = "";
final private int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
final private int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 2;
private String imgPath;
File file;
boolean isphotoselected = false;
private SharedPreferences pref;
Typeface typeface;

String advertId,advertUserName,advertPassword,advertEmail,advertPhone,advertSite,advertImage;
boolean AddFlag= false;

MarshMallowPermission marshMallowPermission;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_updateprofile);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/GandhiSerif-Bold.otf");

    if (toolbar != null) {
        toolbar.setTitle("Profile Update");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    getActionBarTextView();
    marshMallowPermission = new MarshMallowPermission(this);
    if (!marshMallowPermission.checkPermissionForExternalStorage()) {
        marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForExternalStorage();
    }
    if (!marshMallowPermission.checkPermissionForCamera()) {
        marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForCamera();
    }
    if (!marshMallowPermission.checkPermissionForExternalStorage()) {
        marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForExternalStorage();
    }
    imgProfile = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgProfile);
    btnMyadd   = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMyadd);
    btnSaveProfile=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSaveprofile);
    edtEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtEmailid);
    edtName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtName);
    edtNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtphone);
    edtWebsite= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtwebsite);
    txtEmail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    txtname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
    txtWebsite= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtWeb);

    btnMyadd.setTypeface(typeface);
    btnSaveProfile.setTypeface(typeface);
    edtEmail.setTypeface(typeface);
    edtName.setTypeface(typeface);
    edtNumber.setTypeface(typeface);
    edtWebsite.setTypeface(typeface);
    txtEmail.setTypeface(typeface);
    txtname.setTypeface(typeface);
    txtNumber.setTypeface(typeface);
    txtWebsite.setTypeface(typeface);


    pref = getSharedPreferences("loginpreference", MODE_PRIVATE);

    imgProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startDialog(); 
        }
    });

    btnSaveProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            name   = edtName.getText().toString();
            number = edtNumber.getText().toString();
            email  = edtEmail.getText().toString();
            website= edtWebsite.getText().toString();

            boolean flag = emailValidator(email);

            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                edtName.setError("Please Enter Name");
            }else if(number.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                edtNumber.setError("Please Enter Contact Number");
            }else if(flag == false){
                edtEmail.setError("Please Enter Email");
            }else if(website.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                edtWebsite.setError("Please Enter Website");
            }else if(selectedImagePath.equalsIgnoreCase("") || selectedImagePath==null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Select Profile Picture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                new UpdateProfileTask().execute();
            }

        }
    });

    btnMyadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(!AddFlag){
                Toast.makeText(UpdateProfileActivity.this, "Please Update Your Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                AddFlag = true;
                Intent intent =new Intent(UpdateProfileActivity.this, MyAdsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("advertId", advertId);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id==android.R.id.home)
    {
        onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();

}
public boolean emailValidator(String s)
{
    return Pattern.compile("^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$").matcher(s).matches();
}

private TextView getActionBarTextView() {
    TextView titleTextView = null;

    try {
        Field f = toolbar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTitleTextView");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        titleTextView = (TextView)f.get(toolbar);
        titleTextView.setTypeface(typeface);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    }
    return titleTextView;
}


class UpdateProfileTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    String jsonStr = null;
    CustomProgressDialog cd= new CustomProgressDialog();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        cd.showdialog(UpdateProfileActivity.this, "Loading...");

    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        jsonStr = uploadFile();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        cd.dismissdialog();
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                String responce = jsonObj.getString(Constants.LOGIN_TAG);
                String msg = jsonObj.getString(Constants.REG_TAG);

                if(responce.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                    JSONArray jArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

                    if(jArray.length()>0){

                        JSONObject j1 = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
                        advertId = j1.getString("advertId");
                        advertUserName = j1.getString("advertUserName");
                        advertPassword = j1.getString("advertPassword");
                        advertEmail = j1.getString("advertEmail");
                        advertPhone = j1.getString("advertPhone");
                        advertSite = j1.getString("advertSite");
                        advertImage = j1.getString("advertImage");
                        AddFlag = true;
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(UpdateProfileActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(UpdateProfileActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                edtEmail.setText("");
                edtName.setText("");
                edtNumber.setText("");
                edtWebsite.setText("");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private String uploadFile() {
    String responseString = null;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Constants.WEBURL);

    try {
        AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(new AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void transferred(long num) {

            }
        });
        if(isphotoselected){
            file = new File(selectedImagePath);
            //entity.addPart("userfile",selectedImagePath.toString();
            entity.addPart("avtar", new FileBody(file));
            //entity.addPart("filesArray[]",new FileBody(file));
            isphotoselected = false;
        }

        String advartid = pref.getString("advertId", "");
        entity.addPart("action", new StringBody("updateAccount"));
        entity.addPart("advertId", new StringBody(advartid));
        entity.addPart("username", new StringBody(name));
        entity.addPart("email", new StringBody(email));
        entity.addPart("phone", new StringBody(number));
        entity.addPart("site", new StringBody(website));

        httppost.setEntity(entity);

        // Making server call
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            // Server response
            responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
        } else {
            responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "+ statusCode;
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        responseString = e.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        responseString = e.toString();
    }

    return responseString;

}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

 if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
     if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE)
       onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
     else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE)
       onCaptureImageResult(data);
     else if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_CROP) {
       handleCrop(resultCode, data);
     }
   }
 }

 //onCaptureFromCamera

 private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {

    beginCrop(data.getData());
}

//onSelectFromGalleryResult()

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
   Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

   beginCrop(selectedImageUri);
}

private void beginCrop(Uri source) {
   Uri destination = Uri.fromFile(new File(getCacheDir(), "cropped"));
   Crop.of(source, destination).asSquare().start(this);
}

private void handleCrop(int resultCode, Intent result) {
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

      try {
        Bitmap bitmap = handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap(this, Crop.getOutput(result));

        saveToInternalStorage(bitmap);

       mUserProfilePhoto.setImageBitmap(readFromInternalStorage("profile.png"));
       }catch (IOException e){ /* do nothing here */}
    } else if (resultCode == Crop.RESULT_ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(this, Crop.getError(result).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
```

Handle cropping in this method:

```
 private static Bitmap handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap(Context context, Uri selectedImage) throws IOException {
   int MAX_HEIGHT = 1024;
   int MAX_WIDTH = 1024;

   final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
   InputStream imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
   BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);
   imageStream.close();

   // Calculate inSampleSize
   options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT);

   // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
   options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
   imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
   Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);

   img = rotateImageIfRequired(img, selectedImage);
   return img;
}

private static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
                                 int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
  // Raw height and width of image
 final int height = options.outHeight;
 final int width = options.outWidth;
 int inSampleSize = 1;

 if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

     // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
     final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
     final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

     // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee a final image
     // with both dimensions larger than or equal to the requested height and width.
     inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;

     // This offers some additional logic in case the image has a strange
     // aspect ratio. For example, a panorama may have a much larger
     // width than height. In these cases the total pixels might still
     // end up being too large to fit comfortably in memory, so we should
     // be more aggressive with sample down the image (=larger inSampleSize).

     final float totalPixels = width * height;

     // Anything more than 2x the requested pixels we'll sample down further
     final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;

     while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
        inSampleSize++;
     }
   }
   return inSampleSize;
  }

  private static Bitmap rotateImageIfRequired(Bitmap img, Uri selectedImage) throws IOException {

    ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(selectedImage.getPath());
    int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

   switch (orientation) {
     case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
        return rotateImage(img, 90);
     case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
        return rotateImage(img, 180);
     case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
        return rotateImage(img, 270);
     default:
        return img;
   }
 }

 private static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap img, int degree) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(degree);
    Bitmap rotatedImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    img.recycle();
    return rotatedImg;
 }

 //save to internal storage

  private boolean saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap image) {

   try {
     FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput("profile.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

     image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
     fos.close();

     return true;
   } catch (Exception e) {
     return false;
  }
 }

 //read from storage

  private Bitmap readFromInternalStorage(String filename){
  try {
     File filePath = this.getFileStreamPath(filename);
     FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(filePath);
     return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fi);
  } catch (Exception ex) { /* do nothing here */}

   return null;
 }

 //inside onResume

 @Override
 public void onResume(){
   super.onResume();

   Bitmap savedProfilePhoto = readFromInternalStorage("profile.png");

   if (savedProfilePhoto != null){
       mUserProfilePhoto.setImageBitmap(savedProfilePhoto);
   }
}



private void startDialog()
{
    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Upload Pictures Option");
    builder.setMessage("How do you want to set your picture?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""),PICK_IMAGE);

        }

    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i)
        { 
            final Intent intent = new Intent(
                    MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    setImageUri());
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

public Uri setImageUri() {
    // Store image in dcim
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".png");
    Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    return imgUri;
}

public String getImagePath() {
    return imgPath;
}

public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
    try {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of
        // 2.
        int scale = 1;
        while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale *= 2;

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA); cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } else
        return null;
}
}
```

Add this to build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies{
   compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
}
```

Then add this to your AndroidManifest file:

```
 <activity android:name="com.soundcloud.android.crop.CropImageActivity"/>
```

Comment: You meant it doesn't show on your imageView or your server? Either, checkout my answer here ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38465377/make-uploaded-image-remain-after-layout-activity-change/38465786#38465786 should work

Comment: there is a lot of code how can i add it into my activity

Comment: @Eenvincible
ok added but this : onCaptureImageResult(data); appears on red line : onCaptureImageResult and also this appears on red line : mUserProfilePhoto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Since you have already done the selecting from your Gallery:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
        onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
    else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
        onCaptureImageResult(data);
    else if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_CROP) {
        handleCrop(resultCode, data);
    }
  }
}
```

Now, the method `onSelectFromGalleryResult(data)`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
   Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

   beginCrop(selectedImageUri);
}
```

If you are going to crop your images;

```
private void beginCrop(Uri source) {
   Uri destination = Uri.fromFile(new File(getCacheDir(), "cropped"));
   Crop.of(source, destination).asSquare().start(this);
}

private void handleCrop(int resultCode, Intent result) {
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

      try {
        Bitmap bitmap = handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap(this, Crop.getOutput(result));

        saveToInternalStorage(bitmap);

        mUserProfilePhoto.setImageBitmap(readFromInternalStorage("profile.png"));
       }catch (IOException e){ /* do nothing here */}
   } else if (resultCode == Crop.RESULT_ERROR) {
      Toast.makeText(this, Crop.getError(result).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
 }
```

Then if you need to rotate it automatically,

```
private static Bitmap handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap(Context context, Uri selectedImage) throws IOException {
   int MAX_HEIGHT = 1024;
   int MAX_WIDTH = 1024;

   final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
   InputStream imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
   BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);
   imageStream.close();

   // Calculate inSampleSize
   options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT);

   // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);

    img = rotateImageIfRequired(img, selectedImage);
    return img;
}

private static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
   // Raw height and width of image
   final int height = options.outHeight;
   final int width = options.outWidth;
   int inSampleSize = 1;

   if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

       // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
       final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
       final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

       // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee a final image
       // with both dimensions larger than or equal to the requested height and width.
       inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;

       // This offers some additional logic in case the image has a strange
       // aspect ratio. For example, a panorama may have a much larger
       // width than height. In these cases the total pixels might still
       // end up being too large to fit comfortably in memory, so we should
       // be more aggressive with sample down the image (=larger inSampleSize).

       final float totalPixels = width * height;

       // Anything more than 2x the requested pixels we'll sample down further
       final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;

       while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
          inSampleSize++;
       }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
 }

 private static Bitmap rotateImageIfRequired(Bitmap img, Uri selectedImage) throws IOException {

    ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(selectedImage.getPath());
    int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

  switch (orientation) {
      case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
         return rotateImage(img, 90);
      case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
         return rotateImage(img, 180);
      case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
         return rotateImage(img, 270);
      default:
         return img;
     }
 }

 private static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap img, int degree) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(degree);
    Bitmap rotatedImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), matrix, true);
   img.recycle();
    return rotatedImg;
  }
```

To save your image in your device internal storage:

```
 private boolean saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap image) {

   try {
      FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput("profile.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

      image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
      fos.close();

      return true;
   } catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
   }
 }
```

To read from storage:

```
private Bitmap readFromInternalStorage(String filename){
  try {
     File filePath = this.getFileStreamPath(filename);
     FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(filePath);
     return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fi);
  } catch (Exception ex) { /* do nothing here */}

  return null;
}
```

To set on ImageView:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
  super.onResume();

  Bitmap savedProfilePhoto = readFromInternalStorage("profile.png");

  if (savedProfilePhoto != null){
      mUserProfilePhoto.setImageBitmap(savedProfilePhoto);
  }
}
```

To finish things up, if you want to add cropping,

Almost done here:

Add this to your dependencies (build.gradle)

```
dependencies{
     compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
}
```

Finally, in your android manifest file, for cropping library to work, add this:

```
<activity android:name="com.soundcloud.android.crop.CropImageActivity"/>
```

That is all you need to enable selecting image from gallery or taking photo using your camera inside your app!

Comment: can u put it inyo my code because i not understand what i'm going to remove from my code

Comment: Let me create an activity on Github then share code with you

Comment: https://gist.github.com/echirchir/dffdbdaf1478f89d207bda16ac203a80 always remember we can chat too for help

Comment: Let us chat please should be easier

Comment: sorry i'm new at android, on my activity i have other code. Where i'm going to put your code instead my code because i have tried to remove my code and put your but not work. If u can please modify my activity wich i have provided with your code.

Comment: I have updated the code; just complete the pieces left like adding the library for cropping; to build.gradle and androidmanifest;

Comment: ok added but this : onCaptureImageResult(data); appears on red line : onCaptureImageResult and also this appears on red line : mUserProfilePhoto

Comment: Because you need to replace it with your imageView

Comment: onCaptureImageResult(data) this ?